# today is good day

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

sorry for the title but I couldnt post the question i wanted to ask

I'm getting null when i try to console.log(user)
why am i not getting user data from firebase

[image]

I get no error when I compile. not sure I'm getting this error? a

````
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { auth } from '../firebase';

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuth() { return useContext(AuthContext) }

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    const history = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            setUser(user)
            setLoading(false)

            history.push('/chats')
        })
    }, [user, history])

    const value = { user }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {!loading && children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}```
````

Comment: You should expect null before a user is known to be fully signed in.  That will always happen when the page first loads.  If a user was previously signed in before the page was loaded, it will take some time for the user object to become available in a subsequent callback.

Comment: I signed in myself to test it and I get null, also request failed

Comment: You will always get null on the first load.  It takes time to get a user object on the second callback - network calls and I/O are not instant.

Comment: I also get error " Get or Create Session Error Error: Request failed with status code 403 " error msg under null null

Comment: That sounds like a different problem.  You should post that as a different question with your debugging details.